# Concatenated variables as class object

Tags: php

```
$var = 'Foo';
$object = new {$var . 'Controller'}(); // new FooController()
```

Is there any syntax that makes this possible? The example above doesn't work of course.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, simply store the full class name in a variable:

```
$class = $var . 'Controller';
$instance = new $class();
```

Comment: I mean any syntax except for this one.

Comment: Why would you want a different syntax than the correct one? ;)

Comment: I have $var defined as a parameter, and I wanna create object in one line, without creating another variable extending class name :U

Comment: Please don't write ugly code for the sake of reducing the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wouldn't want to use the simplest method available (I'd recommend TheifMaster's method...), the only other ways I could figure this out is to define a function or another class to handle the concatenation and class creation. This is actually more work, although it looks more professional, I must say.

A function could look like:

```
function createObject($prefix, $type)
{
    $objectName = $prefix . $type;

    return new $objectName();
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$var = 'Foo';
$object = createObject($var, 'Controller');
```

Or simply:

```
$object = createObject('Foo', 'Controller');
```

Or define the class creation object, something like:

```
class objectHandler
{
    public function createObject($prefix, $type)
    {
        $objectName = $prefix . $type;

        return new $objectName();
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to use this to create a new object, you just need to call:

```
$var = 'Foo';
$object = objectHandler::createObject($var, 'Controller');
```

Or simply:

```
$object = objectHandler::createObject('Foo', 'Controller');
```

Only reason to use this is if you have multiple Controller classes (FooController, BarController, etc). Other than that, I'd always recommend the KISS method (keep it simple, stupid (That's what it's called, not directed toward you)). That's all I got, let me know if that works for you.